# Simple Membership Tables

Tags: asp.net

I am planning to use Simple Membership for my project. I am creating a Web Application using MVC option in Visual Studio 2013. I change webconfig to point to my MSSQL database. I run the default application and register a user. When I check my database, the tables created are as follows

•   AspNetRoles
•   AspNetUserClaims
•   AspNetUserLogins
•   AspNetUserRoles
•   AspNetUsers

However, when I refer to examples available on the net, I observe that the names of Simple Membership tables are as follows

•   webpages_Membership
•   webpages_Roles
•   webpages_UsersInRoles

Would really appreciate how to move forward - am I missing something while creating the application so that the tables starting with webpages are not created or the tables starting with webpages are renamed in the latest version and it is starting with AspNet.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not implement the ASP.Net Identity.http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Thanks. Do you suggest ASP.NET Identity is better than Simple Membership?  Is Simple Membership still valid or upgraded to a different feature?

Comment: As per my understanding its very simple.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check the link given by you and will revert.